# Weak and strong compactness in $L^2$

Tags: compactness, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Given $g(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}), \ g(x)>0$, let us consider
$$M_g=\{f(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}):|f(x)| \le g(x)\}\subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$$

I have yet proved that $M_g$ is weakly compact in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and now I have to say if it is strongly compact.

A solution to this exercise considers a sequence $f_{n}(x)=\sin(nx)g(x)\in M_g$ which converges weakly, but not strongly, to $0$ and then deduces that $M_g$ is not strongly compact.

Why does it hold?

I thought that if it exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ converging strongly to some limit $f$, then $f$ has necessarily to be $0$ (since it has to be equal to the weak limit). But $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}(\sin(nx)g(x))^2 dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(g(x))^2 dx>0$$ and it holds for every subsequence.

Comment: Hint: use the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: @Jason you mean to compute the limit?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri if I did not wrong that integral splits in two terms, one of them is the right side of the equality I wrote above, while the second one is something like $\int_{\mathbf{R}} cos(nx)g^2(x) dx$ which goes to 0

Comment: with $\mathfrak{F}$ you mean Fourier transform?

Comment: That is $\Im$ the imaginary part.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri There is an error in your calculation - $\operatorname{Im}(e^{2inx})\neq(\sin(nx))^2$. There is also a cosine term.

Comment: @Jason That was a gross miscalculation. My bad, I've removed the erroneous comments and will soon remove this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple consequence of the [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) is that, if $h\in L^1$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int h(x)\cos(nx)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int h(x)\sin(nx)dx=0.$$
Thus, if $\varphi\in L^2$, then since $g\varphi\in L^1$ by Cauchy-Schwarz, one has
$$\int f_n(x)\varphi(x)dx=\int g(x)\varphi(x)\sin(nx)dx\to0$$
as $n\to\infty$, that is, $f_n\to0$ weakly in $L^2$. On the other hand, using $\sin^2x=\frac12(1-\cos(2x))$, one has
$$\int f_n^2\,dx=\frac12\int g^2dx-\frac12\int g^2(x)\cos(2nx)dx\to\frac12\int g^2dx>0,$$
and in particular $f_n\not\to0$ strongly in $L^2$.

Comment: Great answer! +1

Comment: Thank you @Jason for your answer, but why this implies that $M_g$ is not strongly compact?

Comment: I think this is a good exercise for you to try yourself. If $M_g$ were compact, $\{f_n\}$ would have a convergent subsequence. Strong convergence implies weak convergence, and so the limit must be... but this is a contradiction because...

Comment: @Jason I edited my post in its last part. It is correct?